# AWS RDS replica is stuck in Connecting state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication

I have made some changes to my RDS Instance and now my replica is stuck in connecting state.[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what was changed on RDS instance?

Comment: Actually, I have changed the size of the instance just(decreased).

Comment: Please check the recent events for your Amazon RDS instance from the AWS Management Console and check the current state of your DB instance. Check this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ListEvents.html) for checking recent events. I think you should also reach out to AWS support team by creating a ticket if your instance is still in the same state.